# Libgcrypt in C returning 42

Tags: c, encryption, aes, libgcrypt

I would like to preface this with, I am new to C and especially using a lib as large as libgcrypt, so if it is something incredibly simple please be understanding.

So, I have been trying to just encrypt some text just to kinda launchpad from and so that way I get some better confidence before going with just encrypting bytes which is one of the end goals of this little app if youd like to call it that. I have been following [this](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/105743-how-decrypt-encrypt-using-libgcrypt-arc4.html), but still am struggling with getting it to work. The part that really confuses me is that I am passing it the out buffer which has been sized to match that of the in text. I do find it weird that this site tells me to make the out buffer the same size as the input even though usually when encrypting with AES the output is large in terms of bytes. Maybe I missed something that someone more experience can help me with, I have read over their code at least 3-4 times now and I feel like it must be something super simple I am missing here.

### EDIT

**client.c**

```
#include "client.h"

void printGCRYPTError(gcry_error_t err) {
    if (err) {
         {
           fprintf (stderr, "Failure: %s/%s\n",
                    gcry_strsource (err),
                    gcry_strerror (err));
           fprintf (stdout, "Failure: %s/%s\n",
                    gcry_strsource (err),
                    gcry_strerror (err));
         }
    }
}

char* Encrypt(char* in, char* key, char* iv){
    size_t keyLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_keylen(GCRY_CIPHER);
    size_t blkLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_blklen(GCRY_CIPHER);

    if(strlen(key) != keyLength) {
        printf("Invalid Key Size. Expected %zu got %lu\n", keyLength, strlen(key));
        return NULL;
    }
    if(strlen(iv) != blkLength) {
        printf("Invalid BLK/IV Size. Expected %zu got %lu\n", blkLength, strlen(iv));
        return NULL;
    }

    gcry_cipher_hd_t handle;
    gcry_error_t err = 0;

    size_t inLen = strlen(in)+1;
    char * out = malloc(inLen);

    // Open
    err = gcry_cipher_open(&handle, GCRY_CIPHER, GCRY_C_MODE, 0);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Set Key
    err = gcry_cipher_setkey(handle, key, keyLength);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Set IV
    err = gcry_cipher_setiv(handle, iv, blkLength);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Enc
    printf("Encrypting...\n");
    err = gcry_cipher_encrypt(handle, out, inLen, in, inLen);
    printGCRYPTError(err);
    printf("Encrypted.\n");
    gcry_cipher_final(handle);


    //Out
    printf("Plaintext Message: %s\n", in);
    printf("Encrypted Message: ");
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index<inLen; index++) {
        printf("%02X", (unsigned char)out[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Cleanup!
    gcry_cipher_close(handle);

    // Return
    return out;
}

char* Decrypt(char* in, char* key, char* iv){
    size_t keyLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_keylen(GCRY_CIPHER);
    size_t blkLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_blklen(GCRY_CIPHER);

    if(strlen(key) != keyLength) {
        printf("Invalid Key Size. Expected %zu got %lu\n", keyLength, strlen(key));
        return NULL;
    }
    if(strlen(iv) != blkLength) {
        printf("Invalid BLK/IV Size. Expected %zu got %lu\n", blkLength, strlen(iv));
        return NULL;
    }

    gcry_cipher_hd_t handle;
    gcry_error_t err = 0;

    size_t inLen = strlen(in);
    char * out = malloc(inLen);

    // Open
    err = gcry_cipher_open(&handle, GCRY_CIPHER, GCRY_C_MODE, 0);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Set Key
    err = gcry_cipher_setkey(handle, key, keyLength);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Set IV
    err = gcry_cipher_setiv(handle, iv, blkLength);
    printGCRYPTError(err);

    // Dec
    printf("Decrypting...\n");
    err = gcry_cipher_decrypt(handle, out, inLen, in, inLen);
    printGCRYPTError(err);
    printf("Decrypted.\n");
    gcry_cipher_final(handle);

    //Out
    printf("Encrypted Message: ");
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index<inLen; index++) {
        printf("%02X", (unsigned char)out[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Decrypted Message: %s\n", out);

    // Cleanup!
    gcry_cipher_close(handle);

    // Return
    return out;
}

int main() {
    //aesTest();
    char* encrypted = Encrypt("My test message", "sBK0hcXddz6mIKEsBK0hcXddz6mIKEAS", "sBK0uhSAUSUSHKES");
    char* decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, "sBK0hcXddz6mIKEsBK0hcXddz6mIKEAS", "sBK0uhSAUSUSHKES");
}
```

**Console Output**

```
Encrypting...
Encrypted.
Plaintext Message: My test message
Encrypted Message: 153C01DD7821E5113C25D2038F3644F7
Decrypting...
Failure: gcrypt/Invalid length
Failure: gcrypt/Invalid length
Decrypted.
Encrypted Message: 0000000000001000000000000000101400
Decrypted Message:
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: "though usually when encrypting with AES the output is large in terms of bytes" ... define usually. Many modes of AES are streaming modes of operation. You would only get this for CBC/ECB/PCBC without cihpertext stealing. Use counter mode if you want to have the ciphertext size match the input size (in bits / bytes). I don't see any function to calculate the output cipher text, presumably `gcrypt` thinks that is your responsibility to calculate, and do the padding. That's some low level encryption lib if that's the case. The OpenSSL `EVP` functions would be considered high level by comparison.

Comment: Next time please don't leave things out like `GCRY_CIPHER`, where the error is happening etc..

Comment: That wasnt the cause of the answer persay, and I did state that it was AES so padding was regardless of the GCRY_CIPHER would still be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the key issues, I needed padding to be added to my AES plaintext before encryption.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs for [libgcrypt](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-cipher-handles.html):

> Some encryption modes require that gcry_cipher_final is used before
>   the final data chunk is passed to this function.

So I suspect you need to do two things:

1. Check the error code result from `gcry_cipher_encrypt` consistent with how you were doing the prior function calls.
2. Invoke `gcry_cipher_final(handle)` after you call encrypt - presuming you are doing a one-shot encryption of a buffer that is smaller than the block length of your cipher.

Comment: No change, and thats the weird part, I am not getting any errors on execution.

Comment: I owe you an apology, I thought I had it print the error after encrypt. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

As [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267095/5377275) suggested, checking the error returned by `gcry_cipher_encrypt` is useful: it says "Failure: gcrypt/Invalid length."

The root cause appears to be `inLen`:

```c
size_t inLen = strlen(in);
...
err = gcry_cipher_encrypt(handle, out, inLen, in, inLen);
printGCRYPTError(err);
gcry_cipher_final(handle);
```

returns the (expected?) output,

```
Message: My test message!
Encrypted Message = AEDBBB645CA54F16B5A279D77772A97B
```

Comment: I thought I had it print the error after encrypt. My fault. I will test on my end as well.

Comment: I needed padding.

Comment: Another minor question though, if I gave you just the encrypted text, could you decrypt it without the length of the plaintext? Like I want to be able to transmit this data without having to send the plaintext size with it.